# Configure drools with spring. xsd errors

Tags: spring-roo, drools, applicationcontext

I'm trying to create spring roo application with Drools. But I faced with errors in applicationContext.xml.

Error:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'drools:execution-node' of schema namespace 'http://drools.org/schema/
>      drools-spring'
>     - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'drools:execution-node'.

this is a piece of applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd         
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd         
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd         
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd         
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd       
      http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring.xsd">
```

while connecting drools i review this sources:
http://www.packtpub.com/article/drools-integration-modules-spring-framework-apache-camel 
http://blog.mersoft.com/2011/09/07/getting-started-with-drools-5-2 
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/droolsjbpm-integration-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e666

Maybe they will help someone.

hear is the drools bean

```
 <drools:execution-node id="node1" />
```

```
  <drools:resources>

     <drools:resource  type="XSD" source="classpath:model.xsd"/>

     <drools:resource  type="DRL" source="classpath:test.drl"/>

  </drools:resources>
```

Please help me to configure name spaces. and give me more links about Drools spring integration and xml name spaces.

Comment: Can you paste a snippet of your pom.xml where you include the drools libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring.xsd doesn't serve. If you find a URI that serves it properly, your error should go away. An example URI I've found is http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.drools/drools-spring/5.6.0.Final/org/drools/container/spring/drools-spring.xsd/?v=source

I'm trying to find a more reliable reference through in the following stack overflow question: [Location of drools-spring.xsd on git hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172742/location-of-drools-spring-xsd-on-git-hub)

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that the issue is that you're using Spring 3.1, but making use of drools-spring XML config, which loads in some pretty old and derepit Spring dependencies.

I would recommend avoiding the use of the drools-spring XML configuration. Just configure a Spring bean to contain your knowledge base and act as the interface to it.