# Location of drools-spring.xsd on git hub (or reliable source)

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, xsd, drools

My project depends on drools 5.6.0.Final version. As part of that I'm trying to find a uri that I can rely for the `drools-spring.xsd` file. I'm trying to locate a reliable URI for that file I can reference, so that eclipses doesn't show issues, and so that spring can also intercept the requests and replace with the files in the jar as it sees fit.

I can drill into drools-spring-5.6.0.Final.jar in eclipse and see the xsd files in `org.drools.container.spring`. I also can see the xsd file here: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.drools/drools-spring/5.6.0.Final/org/drools/container/spring/drools-spring.xsd/?v=source

Going to drools.org and following their link to github and follow the rename of their group shown in the README file to https://github.com/kiegroup. I've searched this group for the xsd file(s) but have had no luck. e.g. https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/find/5.6.0.Final and https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/find/5.6.0.Final

This makes me think that the xsd files 
are generated? Can someone confirm this and if so, is there a reliable URI that I can reference for this?

Comment: Making a note on my work around. Going to leave this open for the time being in case anyone comes up with a better solution. Since I couldn't find a source from the original authors I ended up creating a in house repo that we'd host internally, which we could use to serve the XSDs, that was we could reference the XSDs via URI on our servers. By hosting it ourselves, we don't have to worry about security concerns, as we got the XSDs from the exploded jar files.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the Drools' team doesn't maintain a hosted version of this schema.

Here you have [an old post](http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/Schema-Error-with-Drools-spring-xsd-td1527960.html) from Mark Proctor explaining it.

As far as I understand, they policy is still the same: do not host any .xsd file.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

The drools-spring.xsd file location on drools website will give you a 404 error. You can have below two approaches which i could find while searching on the net.

One : Host the file on your local machine

Two : Place the .xsd file in the same directory as the location of the xml file referencing it.

Please refer to the below [information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757863(v=vs.85).aspx) . This will give a better understanding of the two methods mentioned above.